# Fetching remote XML from URL using Dart / Flutter

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

I'm having trouble pulling XML data from a url. When I use http.get and print out the response.body - it looks like regular JSON. One of this issues is some of the XML nodes have attributes on them that I need to use. I'm still fairly new to Dart / Flutter so any help is REALLY appreciated. Here's my code for reference:

```dart
  String url = "url_to_data_remote_data";

  Future<DataModel> fetchData() async {
    final response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) 
      return DataModel.fromXML(response.body);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
```

Comment: so the body looks like JSON but you expect XML ? Is this a hybrid webservice that sends out the content depending on your ACCEPT http header? So perhaps it can do both JSON and XML depending on the client.

Comment: I'll try that, but in the event it's not a hybrid service - is there a way to consume XML in Dart / Flutter?

Comment: as to my knowledge http.get doesnt transform the content to something else

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out thanks to @Marc's comments; didn't know a hybrid service was a thing.

Essentially you need to set a header to accept xml. These are the lines of code that fixed my issue:

```dart
    Map<String, String> headers = {"Accept": "text/html,application/xml"};
    final response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
```

Comment: Hi @Nate, I get `Invalid argument(s): Unsupported scheme` because the xml I get don't have the <xml> tag, can you help me?

Comment: I’ll look it over today and let you know what I can figure out

Comment: Sorry, I was trying with // and not http:// BUT when I get to my code on github I get `"<" expected at 1:1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xml](https://pub.dev/packages/xml#-readme-tab-) package to read the XML fetched. Then, you can use it however you like.

If you prefer working with JSON, which I recommend, use [xml2json](https://pub.dev/packages/xml2json#-readme-tab-) package to convert XML to JSON. handling JSON is easier in dart than handling XML.

Comment: the XML I'm using has attributes on that'll be used at a later time so xml2json may not suit the ticket requirements but I'll keep it on my radar.